# footer disappears when running php script

Tags: php

I am having a few issues with a php uploader I have set up and while/once the php script has completed my footer completely disappears.

Here is my php code:

```
<div class="container" id="main">
 <span class="text-image2 img-responsive"> 0-60 Challenge <i class="fa-stop icon-3x" id="square"></i></span>
  <!--CONTENT-->
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <form action="" id="Uploader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
   <br> Name:
<input type="text" id="vistorname" name="vistorname">
<br>
Email:
<input type="text" id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress"> 
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Video" name="submit">
</form>

<div id="progress" style="width:500px;height: 24px;border:1px solid #ccc;"></div>
<!-- Progress information -->
<div id="information" style="width"></div>

 <div id="files" class="files">
    <h3>Uploaded files will appear below</h3>
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
   echo 

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size -- Kept for 500Mb
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
         // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "wmv" && $imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "avi" && $imageFileType != "MP4" && $imageFileType != "jpg") {
        echo "Sorry, only wmv, mp4 & avi files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Total processes
$total = 10;
// Loop through process
for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){
    // Calculate the percentation
    $percent = intval($i/$total * 100)."%";

    // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
    echo '<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#FF0000;\">&nbsp;</div>";
    document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$i.' row(s) processed.";
    </script>';

// This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

// Send output to browser immediately
    flush();

// Sleep one second so we can see the delay
    sleep(1);
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Process completed"</script>';
    $name = $_POST['vistorname'];
$email_address = $_POST['emailaddress'];
    // create email body and send it    

    $to = '[add email]';
    $email_subject = "Crazy Way New 0-60 Video:  $name";
  $email_body = "You have received a new message. Here are the details:\n\n".
                  " \nName: $name \n Email: $email_address\n ".
                  "File: ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). ".";
   $headers = "From: [add email]\n";
   $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";  
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;    

    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. Please note that we only accept wmv, mp4 & avi files.";

    }
}
}
?>

</div>

<p align="center">Please contact us if you are having issues uploading your video. </p></div>

  <!--END Content--> 
  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
  <!-- END FOOTER --> 
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

p.s. I have currently allowed JPG files for speed while testing.

Comment: what is the intended purpose of `return true;`?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. After your `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` I see an empty `echo`. Is this a typo?

Comment: I don't think there was one, it has however enabled the text/footer below this code appear after the the script has completed. But it is still missing during.

Comment: I can be getting it wrong, but it seems you're expecting `footer.php` content to be displayed where your `include` is stated, is that right? Because if it's the case I think you got `include` concept mistaken.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale can you expand on your comment? What is she doing wrong with the `include` ?

Comment: @CodeGodie there could be an empty echo, I really am making this up as I go along. I don't really know much about PHP. I have removed Return true and the footer loads once the upload has completed.

Comment: `include` won't **append** php content to your file, but load it to be used into functions and procedures you call after that. Since I can't see any PHP calls after that `include`, I can't see the point in that.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale Gotcha your comment now makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Also, `include` does not require parenthesis since it's a command and not a bundled function.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale I apologise but I still don't know what you mean?

Comment: @Kirsty so, removing the `return` fixed your issue?

Comment: @AedixRhinedale if i did not use  <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?> what would I use as an alternative to link this 'page' within another 'page'?

Comment: @CodeGodie only part, text below the code still disappears while the uploader is in progress.

Comment: @Kirsty which _"text below"_ specifically?

Comment: @Kirsty There are two different issues here to be considered. 1) PHP interpreter starts working at `<?php` or `<?` and ends at `?>`. If you end it, it won't do anything until it's called for again at a new `<?php`. So, if your first engine call is still working (say, a slow upload process or a long http request), the second one (`include`) will do nothing. Then, assuming it reaches there, we have 2) unless your `footer.php` has `echo`, `print` or other kind of direct, self-called output functions inside it, you will see nothing at all when the interpreter gets there.

Comment: @Kirsty your alternatives can be analyzing your code to consider manually appending both file codes into one and organize its outputs into functions, thus calling them appropriately where their outputs should be shown. You can still use `include` in the place you wish the output should appear, but you have to make sure your file will output something itself as soon as it's included.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale The footer is a separate file so that when content is updated it doesn't need to be updated on every other file it is needed on?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having boils down to where your `sleep()` function is located.

> [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) Delays the program execution for the given number of seconds.

You need to keep in mind that PHP works from top -> down. In your case this is what PHP is doing:

When you first load the page:

1. the top portion HTML is loaded all the way until you `<div id="files"><h3>Uploaded files will appear below</h3>`
2. the first `<?php` is then encountered so now it reads the PHP code
3. Since `$_POST` is not set, your `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` fails and goes to the `else` where the closing `?>` is located
4. lastly it runs the remaining HTML including the `footer.php`

When you click "Upload Video" you are submitting the `form`. When a `form` is submitted it looks at its `action` attribute, if it has something like `test.php`, then it will redirect to that page, in your case it is blank so it will refresh your page sending a POST request. Now your page loads this way:

1. the top portion HTML is loaded all the way until you `<div id="files"><h3>Uploaded files will appear below</h3>`
2. the first `<?php` is encountered so now it reads the PHP code
3. Since `$_POST` is now set, your `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` is a success
4. it sets target directories/files, and your errors if the uploaded files do not match your criteria
5. then you perform an iteration that goes for 10 seconds. This iteration uses `sleep()` which means all parsing of your page is halted up until that point. **Thus making your footer "disappear" momentarily when running the script**.
6. lastly it runs the remaining HTML including the `footer.php`

So as you can see, with your `sleep` in place, your code is halted. To fix it, you need to reconstruct your code, or even better use `AJAX`.

Comment: This is the best answer, but it should be noted that the `for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++)` will block execution regardless of `sleep()`. _However_, using `sleep()` makes the delay noticeable whereas it wouldn't be noticed otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for this @CodeGodie, I think it might be easier if just scrap the whole thing. :S

Answer (score 0):

**Remove `return true;` from your script.**

[Return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) has a specific meaning:

> return returns program control to the calling module. Execution
>   resumes at the statement following the called module's invocation.

In your case, there is no calling module, so the script simply ends whenever a mail is successfully sent.

A simple example:

```
<p> foo bar <p>

<?php
return true;
?>

<p> more stuff </p>
```

outputs:

```
<p> foo bar <p>
```

Comment: Even though what you are saying is true, it should not be the cause of her error.

Comment: @CodeGodie, _"once the php script has completed my footer completely disappears._" and the last statement before the including the footer is `return true;`

Comment: Assuming it does not fall into **else** clase, which would make PHP interpreter going on until the end. We should know about her `footer.php` content.

Comment: I think you are partially right. It seems to have solved some of her problem

Comment: The inclusion of `return` at that point is irrelevant. Even if it's there or not, the whole page will be processed since `footer.php` is inside another PHP engine call.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale, That's not true. With the example I posted, `<p> more stuff </p>` isn't part of an engine call yet is not produced in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You are using that `include` part to achieve the wrong goal. It won't append your file self-outputs to the place it's stated until PHP interpreter reaches its `<?php` starting tag, and it won't reach it until the upload functions are finished. That's why you're facing delay.

Strictly answering your question rather than pointing better practices (since it's not the question scope), you must wrap your whole code inside a single `<?php ?>` PHP matching tag pair. Therefore, consider `echo`ing this

```
</div>
    <p align="center">Please contact us if you are having issues uploading your video. </p>
```

instead of writing it directly in HTML. That way the PHP interpreter will parse the code as just one single thing and you shouldn't face that issue anymore.

**[EDIT]** Also, consider @HPierce's answerd and remove the `return true;` from your code, avoiding a sudden engine interruption.